# Как "спрятать" порт и IP адрес за доменом?

Tags: веб-программирование, minecraft

Всем привет!

У меня есть 2 хостинга: Один хостинг для сайта, другой для сервера Minecraft. С помощью определенного плагина, на сервере Minecraft открывается порт с картой сервера для браузера (сайт с картой), но показывается это на реальном IP адресе сервера (например, 111.123.456.789:11111).
На хосте с сайтом у меня привязан домен test.ru.
Мне надо сделать так, чтобы сайт с картой на реальном IP адресе переадресовывался на домен test.ru, да так, чтобы был спрятан порт и нельзя было пробить этот домен на реальный IP адрес (например, через сервис https://2ip.ru/lookup/ ).

Как такое сделать?

Comment: Ищите reverse proxy

Comment: Это плагин на сервер или что это?

Comment: Хотя бы погуглил для приличия:)

Comment: Разумеется можно, достаточно лишь настроить вам веб-сервер на сайте так, чтобы за частью контента он ходил на другой веб-сервер. Только вот какой веб-сервер у вас там стоит вы не указали, так что точнее сказать невозможно.

Comment: Кстати, вы же в курсе что реальный IP-адрес игрового сервера вы спрятать не можете, потому что к нему должен как-то minecraft подключаться?

Comment: Для подключения всегда нужны IP-адрес и порт. Для подключения домен всегда преобразуется в IP-адрес (а в SRV-записях DNS может храниться ещё и порт). Если вы их попытаетесь спрятать, то к вам просто никто не сможет подключиться

Comment: У меня Bungeecord, который прячет все это.

Comment: Если для работы карты необходимо прямое обращение из браузера на сервер minecraft то вам надо на веб-сервере поставить какую нибудь проксю которая пробросит порт с сервера Minecraft на сам веб сервер и тогда можно будет обращаться из браузера уже по адресу самого веб-сервера, а прокся на нем уже от имени сервера пробросит запрос дальше на адрес minecraft. Искать под вашу ОС web-сервера по фразе "проброс портов", например. (на linux вполне можно реализовать все средствами iptables или использовать ssh-туннели)

Comment: Можно и без проброса порта в каком-нибудь nginx прописать proxy_pass на нужный сервер, только видимо нужно прописать правильный адрес где-то в настройках плагина